# Why is $DISPLAY sometimes :0 and sometimes :1

Tags: bash, environment-variables, xserver

I'm using xmacro to record keyboard shortcuts, which requires a `$DISPLAY` to replay on. But, sometimes my `$DISPLAY` is **:0** and sometimes **:1**, so every time that happens I have to change the value manually. Why does it keep changing, and is there a way to set the `$DISPLAY` value to either **:0** or **:1** permanently? (I can export `DISPLAY=:0` in one terminal, but that doesn't change the value of `$DISPLAY` in new terminals.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number identifies [the display ("a collection of monitors that share a keyboard and mouse")](http://www.xfree86.org/current/X.7.html#sect4)

`:0` is usually the local display (i.e. the main display of the computer when you sit in front of it).

`:1` is often used by services like SSH when you enable display forwarding and log into a remote computer.

It can also be modified by startup scripts which try to "fix" it. To find out whether this is happening, run

```
grep DISPLAY ~/.??*
```

`.??*` is a trick to get all dot files without `..` and `.` (parent and current folder).

If that doesn't print anything, check `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash*` and `/etc/bash*/*` in a similar manner.

I couldn't find a useful manual for xmacro but most X11 application support the option `-d` or `-display` to override `$DISPLAY`.

If this doesn't work, create `xmacro.sh` with this content:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 export DISPLAY=:0
 exec xmacro "$@"
```

Now invoke the tool with `xmacro.sh` and it should always work.

Comment: On a big-iron machine you could have dozens of `DISPLAY` devices sharing one CPU and X "server". (The X client vs server terminology is confusing, so I'm not even trying to be correct.)

Comment: An X client is an application that sends rendering commands to an X server. An X server is something that can execute those rendering commands. What's confusing is that the X server often runs on the PC under one's desk while the X client sometimes runs on some remote server or locally.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to look that up again, but there you are (-: