# Is that normal that $DISPLAY environment variable value is 1?

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-20.04, xserver

Well, I have some sort of problems and that one may be the root of them. I just want to know if that output is normal.

```sh
~$ echo $DISPLAY 
:1
```

Is there any problem? According to my research, it should be `:0`.

[Why is $DISPLAY sometimes :0 and sometimes :1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394974/why-is-display-sometimes-0-and-sometimes-1)

> `:0` is usually the local display (i.e. the main display of the computer when you sit in front of it).

> `:1` is often used by services like SSH when you enable display forwarding and log into a remote computer.

Although it is my local display, `$DISPLAY` is `:1`. Thus, **how can we fix the problem(if it is a problem)?**

Additional information: While I log in, the screens is flickering.

**System Info**:

```sh
~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               ********@*************** 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 20URS0BG00 ThinkPad T15g Gen 1 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 hours, 32 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3895 (dpkg), 26 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: x-terminal-emul 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-10750H (12) @ 5.000GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA 01:00.0 NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e91 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 6676MiB / 31894MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: This question is probably more suited on https://superuser.com, https://unix.stackexchange.com, or https://askubuntu.com If you do ask there, be sure to explain more clearly what the problem is - I'm not sure what "the screen clips" means - and why you think this value might be relevant.

Comment: It is like in the gif at https://gifer.com/en/Dk5E . However it takes only 1 or 2 seconds on login.